# Uninstall node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

node-gyp was installed as a dependency of one of the modules I have used. Since then, every time I run a `npm install` command I am greeted with around a minute of my console being spammed with errors which are seemingly caused by node-gyp.

I don't want anything to do with node-gyp, but it seems to resist any attempt to uninstall it. I have tried using `npm remove node-gyp`, but with no results.

Comment: If you have installed it globally, you need to specify `-g` to the uninstall command: `npm -g uninstall node-gyp`.

Comment: @Derlin Thank you! That was easier than I thought. If you could make this an answer I would happily mark it as correct.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @Derlin I may have spoken prematurely, I still have errors when using `npm uninstall [package]`

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed it globally (which I suppose given your description), you need to specify `-g` to the uninstall command:

```
npm -g uninstall node-gyp
```